# Synchronization across threads in nodejs

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I am relatively new to nodejs. I read a couple blogs on how to spawn pool of background workers, send them work, and retrieve results from them.

- https://threads.js.org/usage#basics
- https://blog.logrocket.com/a-complete-guide-to-threads-in-node-js-4fa3898fe74f/
- https://medium.com/@sararavi14/node-js-threading-model-badf7bb5fffa

However, say i have some sort of collection in parent/main thread, which is to be accessed by child workers. How do I do I gaurantee thread safety in this case?
how do I do things such as below (**id_map** a **dictionary** for example):

```
lock(id_map) {
   ... do some operations on id_map ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should read more about callbacks and closures in nodejs. i understand that your question is some technical, but in nodejs , we deal with load balancing if we have threads, and generally callbacks instead of process blocking. this is where nodejs differs, nonblocking io ...

Comment: I am trying to review Promise: producer/consumer -- https://javascript.info/promise-basics